# Can I add my GitHub profile page and its subpages to my Google Search Console account?

Tags: google-search-console, social-media

[image: Google Search Console - Add Property]

Google Search Console offers the ability to add properties to your account based on a URL prefix. Is it possible to add my social network profiles to my Google Search Console?

The problem I'm having is the verification step, since I can't upload a file to the required path, I can't insert a meta tag, and have no control over the DNS.

Note I'm trying to get this working with GitHub, but I could see a similar case if someone was looking to manage their Twitter (X?) page through Google Search Console as well.

Comment: Might not be possible: https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/108980357/index-instagram-and-facebook-profile-through-google-search-console?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you can't add this.

Because Google Search Console is known as the process of registering people's domain names in the Google search engine. If you are not the domain owner of the link you added, you cannot do this.